# Collection of monotone functions on compact subinterval is closed in uniform norm

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, approximation-theory

Let $C([a,b])$ be the space of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ in the uniform topology.Suppose that $[c,d]\subset[a,b].$ Show that

$M=${$f\in C([a,b]):f$ is monotone on $[c,d]$} is a closed set.

I don't have any specific idea, i tried some contradiction but doesn't work. Next I tried showing compliment is open, does not work.

Comment: The union of finitely many closed sets is closed. $M$ is the union of the sets of functions that are non-decreasing resp. non-increasing on $[c,d]$.

Comment: please elaborate little bit, i didn't understand second part, how it relates to union of finitely many closed sets..

Comment: $M = A\cup B$. So if you can show that $A$ and $B$ are closed, it follows that $M$ is closed.

Comment: I am sorry, i don't know how to show A is closed..

Comment: No help!!!!!!!!

Comment: You could look at the pointwise limit of a sequence of non-decreasing functions.

Comment: O i see, i didn't know before that point wise limit of increasing function is increasing, Now i got it... Thanks